# Multiple Word/Office Add-ins interacting

Tags: office-js, office-addins, word-addins

I am designing a Word add-in which has an "search" interface, and my user will want open several of the "search results" in new tabs (or similar UX) to see additional information about each search result. They will want to open each new result in a new tab.

I am thinking of delegating the "multiple tabs" workflow to the Word add-in framework by having my "search" task pane automatically open a second Task Pane which when given an ID to the "search result," will display the result in full.

Is this possible & recommended?

Questions re: possibility:

- will these 2 task panes need to be part of 2 separate word add-ins?
- can one word add-in (or task pane) pass information to another?
- can one word add-in (or task pane) open another one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible at present for one add-in to open another or to pass information reliably to another. I recommend that you implement multiple tabs in the same task pane.

Comment: I was perusing docs about auto-open which hints related functionality but a deadend for my specific use case. For posterity: https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-Add-in-Commands-Samples/tree/master/AutoOpenTaskpane and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/automatically-open-a-task-pane-with-a-document.